# (discord.js) trying to make my bot read user game activity and change voice channel to the game's name

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

trying to make my bot read user game activity and change voice channel to the game's name but I have no clue how to do so, new to JavaScript and this is the only feature I've been wanting to do for a while. would really appreciate help from a JavaScript expert.

main idea is to make the bot work automatically without inputting any command, the bot gets info on what most of the people in the certain voice channel play and adds the game name to the voice channel name for example "Room02" => "Room02 - Some Game".